# Cell Tower distance measurement

Tags: rtl-sdr

I am developing a hobby project to detect/measure the distance between my cell phone and a cell tower (GSM tower).
I am newbie. I don't even know whether this is possible or not.
I have following hardware:

1. Raspberry Pi 3
2. RTL2832u

I am planning to use OpenBTS and the FreeSwitch stack in the future for advanced feature development.

Comment: Hobby projects like this are great.  You can certainly learn a lot by doing it yourself.  To do this with a RPi you'll want a GSM module to find "my cell tower"  But of course, there are other ways to simply detect cell tower signals.  Have you looked at the apps available for smart phones?  I saw one a while back which identified the tower my phone was connected to and put it up on a map, along with signal strength info.

Comment: Yes. The android app [OpenSignal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal) and [RF Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotrod.utility.rfsignaltrackereclair) is real helpful. [Cell2GPS](http://www.cell2gps.com/) too is great website. But I am planning to develop same on Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: If you implemented this project can I get the details please.I have a plan to use this technique in an another way.please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to capture the [GSM Cell ID](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_ID). This uniquely identifies a particular GSM site. You can then lookup this ID in a database such as one offered by [Cobain](https://combain.com) to determine the tower location. If your application serves a very limited geography, you could build your own database to suit your needs.

In order to calculate distance, you will need to geo locate your receive site through a GPS signal, manual entry, or other means. You could then use Google Map services to show the two points and the distance between them.